# Doctrine - Store ArrayCollection keys

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Whenever I use an ArrayCollection with Doctrine ORM (2.3, PHP > 5.4), and associate the object values with a key in the collection (such as when using the `set` method), the values get stored correctly in the database. But when I want to retrieve the collection from the entity, the keys don't get retrieved and instead they use a numeric index.

For instance, if I have the following classes:

```
/** @Entity */
class MyEntity
{
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="MyOtherEntity", mappedBy="mainEntity") */
    private $myArray;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myArray = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addOtherEntity($key, $value)
    {
        $this->myArray->set($key, $value);
    }

    ...
}

/** @Entity */
class MyOtherEntity
{
    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyEntity", inversedBy="myArray") */
    private $mainEntity;
    ...
}
```

The `set` method works properly, but when I retrieve the information the keys in `$myArray` are gone.

How do I make the ORM remember properly the keys? Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is solved in the following way:

```
/** @Entity */
class MyEntity
{
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="MyOtherEntity", mappedBy="mainEntity", indexBy="key") */
    private $myArray;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myArray = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addOtherEntity($key, $value)
    {
        $this->myArray->set($key, $value);
    }

    ...
}

/** @Entity */
class MyOtherEntity
{
    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyEntity", inversedBy="myArray") */
    private $mainEntity;

    /** @Column(name="MyOtherTable_Key", type="string", unique=true, length=50)
    private $key;
    ...
}
```

You also need `MyOtherTable_Key` in your db schema so it can store the key properly.

Remember to always set the object key into the property. One way to do so is to declare the key in the constructor.

```
public function __construct($key)
{
    $this->key = $key;
}
```

Comment: Is this the solution to getting the response to be keyed.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html

Comment: Wait what response? The query one?

Comment: horribly worded.  When serializing the entity as json having the array collection keyed by an element value.  It is btw.  thanks.

Comment: OH. If you call `toArray()` on the collection you will have a key-value array with the keys being the same ones as the stored in the database, so yes, this will return a key-value array to the JS script when serialized. If you need a class to be serializable though always remember to make it implement `JsonSerializable` which is part of the PHP default library. Btw if it doesn't work for you please do answer so I can give you another solution.