# Named collection keys in ArrayCollection

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, arraycollection

I'm looking for a way to have an associative array keys for a **ODM** `ArrayCollection`.

The entity has the following mapping:

```
/**
 * $fields
 *
 * The entities fields
 *
 * @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="JobboardEntity\Entity\EntityField", sort={"name"="asc"}, cascade={"all"})
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 */
protected $fields;

/**
 * addField
 *
 * Add a single field to the field collection
 *
 * @param EntityField $field The field to add
 */
public function addField(EntityField $field)
{
    $this->fields[$field->getFieldName()] = $field;
}
```

Notice in the `addField` method I am giving the item a index of `$field->getFieldName()`.

Unfortunately, Doctrine forgets this key and returns an `ArrayCollection` with *numeric* indexes rather than the previously set strings.

This means that in order to correctly implement `$this->hasField($fieldName)` or `$this->getField($fieldName)` I would need to loop over the collection and test the `fieldName` value

For example

```
public function hasField($fieldName)
{
    foreach($this->fields as $field) {
        if ($fieldName === $field->getFieldName()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This, in my option, is a poor solution as I would need to load the entire collection to just check the key!

Having [looked into the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303742/doctrine-store-arraycollection-keysn) I can see that **ORM** has [this implemented with `IndexBy` mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html#working-with-indexed-associations).

Is there any similar functionality for Doctrine ODM? What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Collection Strategies](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/collection-strategies.html#set).

If you use @ODM\ReferenceMany(strategy="set") (works with EmbedMany as well) the collection will be stored as as BSON Object with the respective keys being set on load:

I'm not entirely sure about performance impact in the DB itself. I guess storing the collection as BSON Object is a bit slower but as you said, it's not a good thing to load the entire collection (and the entities you're checking against) and it helps to keep the code a bit cleaner.